# Why does this dynamic string creation throw exc_bad_access error after a fixed number?

Tags: c, string, pointers, exc-bad-access, realloc

Okay, so I'm trying to store the text from a file in a string, and everything was working OK until I noticed I wasn't reallocating the memory correctly, and it shouldn't be working.

This is my `main` function before correcting it:

```
FILE * file;
char * quijote, thisChar;
unsigned int writingAt = 0;

file = fopen("quijote.txt", "r");
quijote = malloc(1);

if (file != NULL) {
    while (1) {
        thisChar = (char)fgetc(file);
        if (thisChar == EOF) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("strlen(quijote) = %lu; writingAt = %i\n", strlen(quijote), writingAt);
            quijote = (char *) realloc(quijote, (sizeof(quijote) + 1));
            quijote[writingAt] = thisChar;
            quijote[writingAt + 1] = '\0';
            writingAt++;
        }
    }
} else {
    perror("fopen");
}
fclose(file);
```

It works perfectly, and correctly stores all of the file in the string. Note that memory reallocation is incorrect, as `sizeof(quijote)` always has the same value (8) so theoretically it shouldn't be working.

Now, when I corrected the reallocation, it randomly throws an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when writingAt=135167. This is the "corrected" `main` function:

```
FILE * file;
char * quijote, thisChar;
unsigned int writingAt = 0;

file = fopen("quijote.txt", "r");
quijote = malloc(1);

if (file != NULL) {
    while (1) {
        thisChar = (char)fgetc(file);
        if (thisChar == EOF) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("strlen(quijote) = %lu; writingAt = %i\n", strlen(quijote), writingAt);
            quijote = (char *) realloc(quijote, (writingAt + 1));
            quijote[writingAt] = thisChar;
            quijote[writingAt + 1] = '\0';
            writingAt++;
        }
    }
} else {
    perror("fopen");
}
fclose(file);
```

And these are the last lines the program prints before the error:

```
strlen(quijote) = 135162; writingAt = 135162
strlen(quijote) = 135163; writingAt = 135163
strlen(quijote) = 135164; writingAt = 135164
strlen(quijote) = 135165; writingAt = 135165
strlen(quijote) = 135166; writingAt = 135166
strlen(quijote) = 135167; writingAt = 135167
Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x10fc20000)
```

I don't understand why the previous code worked and this doesn't, or why the program throws the error in that specific number. Also, I've tried reallocating to size 1 like this: `quijote = (char *) realloc(quijote, 1);` and for some reason it also works...

Comment: There is a *reason* why `fgetc()` returns an `int`. You are thus using it incorrectly. Also, `sizeof()` != `strlen()`.

Comment: @user3121023 Ok, but remove the cast.

Comment: @EOF what is the reason? Yeah I know sizeof and strlen aren't the same, thus why the first function is incorrect... Any idea on why it works though?

Comment: @EOF And `strlen()` will not help here.

Comment: @dieortin Because it invokes UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR, since it's UNDEFINED it might seem to be working.

Comment: @iharob shouldn't I be getting an error while trying to access an index that is bigger than the size of the array?

Comment: @dieortin No, no error at all. That's how c is. You have fine grained control over everything, thus you MUST be very careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You allocate `writingAt + 1` characters, then access `quijote[writingAt + 1]` which is undefined behaviour - it's the (writingAt + 2)'th character, which is one more than the actual number of characters allocated.